# Failed to load .so in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanted to load a .so file: System.loadLibrary("example");
 but i faced with this error!!
this is the error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.name.ex, PID: 30737

```
                                               java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: file offset for the library "/data/app/com.name.ex-1/lib/arm/example.so" >= file size: 0 >= 0
                                                   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
                                                   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                   at com.name.ex.example<clinit>(example.java:582)
                                                   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1020)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1005)
                                                   at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:670)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6395)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might have placed the native assembly for [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) into the wrong directory ...or the file-size is indeed `0`. it's ordinary called `armeabi-v7a` instead of `arm`, for example (the `jniLibs` path might need to be adjusted, depending how your project looks alike):

```
app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a
```

in the module-level `build.gradle` one can define the location:

```
android {

    ...

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir "src/main/jniLibs"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your solution solved my issue but now it cants find my .h file in jni/lib/include :/

Comment: install the NDK ...so that these headers will become known. or put the .h file where it is being expected... that path can he adjusted similarly.